# Rate of change of area of a square with respect to side length

Tags: derivatives

I have been asked to find the rate of change of the area of a square with respect to the length of its side when the side is 4ft.

This is how I thought I should do it.

Area=$s^2$

$\frac{d(a)}{d(s)}=2 s$

Now I thought that I could just replace s with 4ft, however the answer is $\frac{8 \text{ft}^2}{\text{ft}}$,

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$8 ft^2/ft = 8 ft$, which is the answer your formula gives.  So your work appears to be correct.

Comment: But writing it as 8 square feet per foot emphasizes that it's the rate of change of an area with respect to a length.

Comment: Thats okey but it is not only this question where de represent the answer in this way, I just dont understand why? Why not simplify?

Comment: Okey thats why they do it, sorry didnt update the browser before I asked the question!